# Open iphone Messages settings from app is not working in ios 11.0and later versions

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

From the app, I want to open Message settings. In ios 10 it was working fine. But after updating the phone to new ios version i.e. ios 11.0, it doesn't work anymore.I tried following a line of codes but it didn't work.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=MESSAGES")!) 

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"App-Prefs:root=MESSAGES")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

it did change in iOS11  https://github.com/phynet/iOS-URL-Schemes

seems that util now this is no specific way...

Answer (score 0):

Apple was not give option to open message settings. you can give instruction to your users by alert and navigate the user.

I think this will help you

Answer (score -1):

Swift 3

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "sms:")!)
```

Swift 4

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "sms:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it's not working for message settings, it's open a SMS screen. Do you have any other suggestions..